# Going-up but not lying over?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R \subseteq S$ be an extension of commutative rings with identity.  Assume $1_R = 1_S$.  This extension satisfying *going-up* if for any inclusion of primes $P_1 \subseteq P_2$ of $R$, and any prime $Q_1$ of $S$ lying over $P_1$, there exists a prime $Q_2$ of $S$ lying over $P_2$ with $Q_1 \subseteq Q_2$.  This extension satisfies *lying over* if any prime of $R$ has a prime of $S$ lying over it.

> If $R$ and $S$ are integral domains, then going-up implies lying over, because one can take $P_1 = Q_1 = 0$.  If not though, can we have going-up but not lying over?

Comment: I hope that meanwhile you found out that GU $\implies$ LO for *any* ring extension. For a proof see [here](https://books.google.ro/books?id=1AZfvv-Ava0C&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187&dq=GU+implies+LO&source=bl&ots=uoPxpGTkvf&sig=klEWZa0xnMkUJzefFuQ_GFFd9Z4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7s-2B1_vPAhVEtRQKHcHFCpsQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=GU%20implies%20LO&f=false).

Comment: Note the proof of GU $\Rightarrow$ LO requires Zorn's lemma. Another proof may be found in I. Kaplansky, *Commutative Rings*, p. 192. However, Kaplansky's proof leaves a little detail to the reader to guess. This detail is spelled out by Rowen in his *Graduate Algebra: Commutative View*.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\p{\mathfrak{p}}
\def\q{\mathfrak{q}}
\def\Spec{\operatorname{Spec}}$user26857 already pointed out that GU $\Rightarrow$ LO for any ring extension, and for the proof they linked L. H. Rowen, *Graduate Algebra: Commutative View*. For those that don't have access to the book, I will copy down the proof here. Even though Rowen states and proves the result only for a ring extension, the proof is basically the same for an arbitrary ring morphism, as done below. (I also wanted to rewrite Rowen's proof with notation *à la Bourbaki* for posterity; I got into trouble while disentangling Rowen's symbols and some typos. Contrary to Rowen's notation, for me the symbols '$\subset$' and '$\subseteq$' mean the same. Below, I will denote strict containment by '$\subsetneq$'.)

First we make the following observation: in any ring $B$, an ideal $\mathfrak{b}\subset B$ is prime if and only if for all ideals $I,J\supsetneq \mathfrak{b}$ we have $IJ\supsetneq \mathfrak{b}$. This is because (1) $\mathfrak{b}$ is prime if and only if $B/\mathfrak{b}$ is an integral domain and (2) a ring is an integral domain iff the product of non-zero ideals is a non-zero ideal.

The following numbering is from Rowen's book. Given a ring morphism $\varphi:A\to B$ and an ideal $\mathfrak{b}\subset B$, we denote $\mathfrak{b}^c=\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{b})$, the *contraction* ideal of $\mathfrak{b}$ by $\varphi$.

> **Lemma 6.30.** (i) If $S\subset B$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $B$, then any ideal $\mathfrak{b}\subset B$ maximal with respect to $\mathfrak{b}\cap S=\varnothing$ is prime.
>
> (ii) Let $\varphi:A\to B$ be a ring morphism and let $\p\subset A$ be prime. If $J\subset B$ is an ideal such that $ J^c\subset\p$, then there is an ideal $\q\subset B$ containing $J$, maximal with respect to $\q^c\subset \p$, and any such $\q$ is in $\operatorname{Spec}B$.

*Proof.* (i) Suppose $\mathfrak{b}$ is such an ideal and let $I,J\supsetneq \mathfrak{b}$ be ideals of $B$. By maximality of $\mathfrak{b}$, there are $s_1\in I\cap S$ and $s_2\in J\cap S$, so that $s_1s_2\in IJ\cap S$; hence $IJ\supsetneq \mathfrak{b}$.

(ii) Since $A\setminus\p$ is multiplicatively closed, so is $S=\varphi(A\setminus\p)$. The poset of ideals
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{J}
&=\{\mathfrak{b}\subset B
\mid J\subset\mathfrak{b}\text{ and }\mathfrak{b}\cap S=\varnothing\}\\
&=\{\mathfrak{b}\subset B
\mid J\subset\mathfrak{b}\text{ and }\mathfrak{b}^c\subset\p\}
\end{align*}
is non-empty (since $J\in\mathcal{J}$) and satisfies the hypothesis of Zorn's lemma. Thus, $B$ has an ideal $\mathfrak{q}\supset J$ maximal  with respect to $\q\cap S=\varnothing$. By (i), $\q\in\operatorname{Spec}B$. $\square$

> **Lemma 6.31.** GU implies LO for any ring morphism $A\to B$.

*Proof.* Let $\p\in\Spec A$. By Lemma 6.30(ii) (take $J=0$) there is $\mathfrak{q}_0\in\Spec B$ with $\q_0^c\subset\p$. By GU, there is $\mathfrak{q}\in\Spec B$ with $\q_0\subset \q$ and such that $\q^c=\p$. $\square$

Comment: The typos in Rowen's book I refer to are in Lemma 6.30(i): in the statement, he writes '$\neq\varnothing$' instead of '$=\varnothing$'; in the proof, he writes '$IJ\subsetneq$' instead of '$IJ\supsetneq$'.